# ng2 date pipe formatting triggers 'No locale data' error in karma test

Tags: angular, karma-runner, shim

I have a basic AngularJS2 project created with angular-cli. I start with the freshly generated project. In `app.component.ts`, I store a date:

```
theDate = new Date();
```

I display it using a date pipe:

```
{{theDate | date}}
```

The date is correctly displayed and formatted as expected. But if I run `ng test`, I get the following error:

```
Failed: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:4:3 caused by: No locale data has been provided for this object yet.
g@node_modules/karma-intl-shim/lib/shim.js:11:1866
F@node_modules/karma-intl-shim/lib/shim.js:11:8835
k@node_modules/karma-intl-shim/lib/shim.js:11:8335
```

The failing test is:

```
it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
}));
```

`package.json`:

```
"karma-intl-shim": "^1.0.3"
```

`karma.conf`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    ...
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli', 'intl-shim'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-intl-shim'),
      ...
    ] ...
```

Remarks:

- angular-cli "1.0.0-beta.16"
- I've switched to `PhantomJS` for convenience but the same occurs with `Chrome`.
- I did perform `npm install --save` to install dependencies.

In order to make things easier to the reader, the project is stored [here](https://github.com/YouriAckx/ng2-datepipe-issue).

What is the missing piece? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually came to this trying to find solution, at the end this worked for me and all my tests are passing with PhantomJS

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {  
  "intl": "^1.2.5",
..
   },
 "devDependencies": {
    "karma-intl-shim": "^1.0.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "~2.1.7",
}
```

In Karma.conf.js

```
 - frameworks: [... 'intl-shim' ..],
 - plugin: [... require('karma-intl-shim') . ]
 -  files: [{
                pattern: './node_modules/Intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js',
                watched: false
            },]
```

UPDATE: Depending on OS the path might vary for Intl like

```
                pattern: './node_modules/Intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js',
```

VS

```
                pattern: './node_modules/intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js',
```

Notice the Capital "I"

Answer (score 1):

In case that you have an older `angular-cli (1.0.1)` project, there is a missing import in `polyfills.ts`

>> **Go to**

*Application Imports* section, and bellow this line `import 'intl';  // Run npm install --save intl.`

>> **Paste this**

`import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en'`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to the `karma.conf.json` file in the `files` section:
    `'./node_modules/Intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js'`

Comment: My karma.conf.json file contains files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ] , should it be update to files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }, './node_modules/Intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js'
    ]

Comment: @NaveedAhmed, you may want to check my answer here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182840/no-locale-data-error-in-karma-test-using-phantomjs/43228904#43228904